# Hyperledger fabric: docker-compose orderer Exit 2

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

After starting the image, orderer cannot start normally

````
2021-02-02 11:17:13.897 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> PANI 005 Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Consortiums sub-group config: Attempted to define two different versions of MSP: OrgcppMSP
panic: Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Consortiums sub-group config: Attempted to define two different versions of MSP: OrgcppMSP```
````

Comment: Please add more details

Comment: Could you attach the `configtx.yaml` file used to create the genesis.block of system-channel to the question?